# http://siteAddress/assets/vendors/global/fonts/@fortawesome/fa-solid-900.ttf (Internal Server Error) when run site on the server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i create a site with angular 9 .

when i run site on the local its work good and show the icons good , but when i run site on the server it show mw this error :

> http://siteAddress/assets/vendors/global/fonts/@fortawesome/fa-solid-900.ttf  (Internal Server Error)

now in server i put the build files in the `app` folder and i not have this folder in local . i think this error for this .

```
 src: url("assets/vendors/global/fonts/@fortawesome/fa-solid-900.eot");
src: url("assets/vendors/global/fonts/@fortawesome/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/assets/vendors/global/fonts/@fortawesome/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/assets/vendors/global/fonts/@fortawesome/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("/assets/vendors/global/fonts/@fortawesome/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/assets/vendors/global/fonts/@fortawesome/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg");
```

**now how can i solve this problem ????**

Comment: If you are just trying to use `font-awesome` icons in an `angular` project, the simplest way around it is to use the `angular-fontawesome` package as described at https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: i not have time for change .

Comment: It's done in less time than posting this question.